# What are .xlog files and what can they be used for?

Tags: internal-storage, file-system, storage, privacy, data-monitoring

Im cleaning the storage on my S10+ and I noticed in the WeChat folder (Tencent) there are a bunch of .xlog files totalling nearly 3gb of space.

I know the controversies of using WeChat but I rarely use the app and yet it uses more storage than Whatsapp.

On a sidenote this 3gb is not part of cache memory or storage for the app itself which is (700mb). After deleting the app data and reinstalling the app and not signing in but not using the app it jumps back up to 700 mb. 450mb for the app itself and 250 for data. There shouldn't be any substantial data from doing nothing. This is compared to Whatsapp which only uses 700mb total and I use it daily and have multiple chats saved and media as well.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This has some explanation https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/xlog-files.1031116/

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I saw that thread while researching but it is the only only one that mentions .xlog files and im trying to find more info on that file format and what it could be used for. It doesnt seem to be a widespread issue.